# Configure JSON in Arkit to visualize NPM modules in Package.json

Tags: node.js, json, npm, architecture

I am using the following npm package named [arkit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/arkit) in order to create architecture diagrams of node.js projects, but I am unable to visualize npm packages (**dependencies folder**) in my node.js application architecture as depicted in the examples of Arkit and Vue/Nuxt TodoMVC, I tried to follow the json configuration of each of their respective arkits but either they are non-existent like in Vue or vague like in Arkit itself.
I used the config given in arkit configuration example but I end up with all dependencies of main dependencies [like this](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/68988102/89713956-b7403300-d9b4-11ea-9394-53102baee83c.png). I tried the following config

```
{ "$schema": "https://arkit.pro/schema.json", 
"excludePatterns": ["test/**", "tests/**", "**/*.test.*", "**/*.spec.*"], 
"components": [ 
{ "type": "Dependency", 
"patterns": ["node_modules/**/*.js"] }, 
{ "type": "Component", 
"patterns": ["**/*.js", "**/*.jsx"] 
} 
], 
"output": [ 
{ "path": "arkit.svg", 
"groups": [ { "first": true, "components": ["Component"] },
 { 
"type": "Dependencies", 
"components": ["Dependency"] 
} 
] 
} 
] 
}
```

but it crashed during architecture generation, I also emailed the owner of this npm package and one other person who [successfully](https://github.com/dyatko/arkit/issues/195) managed to do so, but they are busy to guide me in configuring JSON of arkit.
Can I use the for-of loop in the JSON config file in order to get only those node_modules which are included in package.json as I don't want to get additional sub-dependencies of the main npm packages in the architecture representation as depicted in the link shared above!

TL;DR
I want diagrams with dependencies like [these](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dyatko/arkit-editor/master/arkit.svg) but I am getting [this](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/68988102/89713956-b7403300-d9b4-11ea-9394-53102baee83c.png)
I tried, adding --depth=0 in the command line "npx arkit --config test.json --depth=0" but no luck

Answer (score 0):

I think arkit expects output.path to be an array - but you are passing it a string. Try using the modified config:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://arkit.pro/schema.json",
    "excludePatterns": ["test/**", "tests/**", "**/*.test.*", "**/*.spec.*"],
    "components": [{
            "type": "Dependency",
            "patterns": ["node_modules/*"]
        },
        {
            "type": "Component",
            "patterns": ["**/*.js", "**/*.jsx"]
        }
    ],
    "output": [{
        "path": ["arkit.svg"],
        "groups": [{
                "first": true,
                "components": ["Component"]
            },
            {
                "type": "Dependencies",
                "components": ["Dependency"]
            }
        ]
    }]
}
```

Comment: It does not work, I think some modification is required in node_modules/"something"

Comment: I've made that change, as well. Forgot to mention it. Did you use the config I put in as-is?

Comment: Yes, I used the config as-is, can you kindly guide me in modifying node_modules part?

Comment: Could you post the error you're getting? That might help make it easier to figure out what is going on.

Comment: did you use any depth in your arkit command line? like for example "npm list --depth=0"

Comment: No. I haven't used any depth option

Comment: but have you been able to get dependencies like [these](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dyatko/arkit-editor/master/arkit.svg)?

Answer (score 0):

It's working on Ubuntu as if there are more reasons to hate Windows 10. I implemented the package.json config of the authors Vue application and viola it worked like a charm. 2 months of looking for answers and trying everything on Windows, Ubuntu did the trick